# how to remove the extra space left at the end of the page in javascript parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am working on a project and i used a parallax for images and for some div's but because of some reason there is some space is left at the end of the parallax.
Please help me to remove the space at the end of the page here is the link to the webpage [explore-studio](https://zedagehelp.000webhostapp.com/) |and| [here is the link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg8fY.png)

Comment: please use chome or firefox for browsing as this website is under construction.

Comment: can you update the question with a screenshot for the problem, because I didn't find any extra space

Comment: i will try to upload the image but till that time you can check the extra space between the codeburner parallax and php image.

Comment: i think there will be any problem in link thats why you will be displayed unaux.com.So i will try to update the link in 2 minutes.Thanks

Comment: i have uploaded the local server image but the contents are same on the online server.

Comment: dear your code has a lot of miss, I found out that the extra space coming from the above `divs` try to inspect element then remove `divs` the space will decrease until it reach zero space, best solution at the moment is to start cleaning your code before you face more problems like this and even worse

Comment: can you please help me out from where i should start editing my code.I make these mistakes because i am a learner and i am only in class 9th.

Comment: listen my friend I found that the major issue is coming from css `transform` there is always change with the transform value depending on scroll, add this to your css: `.first-work-front-img-holder { transform: none !important;}` this should remove the space

Comment: but this will cause the parallax effect to stop working.please find a diffrent solution.

Comment: no this will not, just try it on the inspector of chrome

Comment: this will effect because the div .first-work-front-img-holder is having a greater scrolling speed than that the div had next to it.You can observe this by scrolling slowly.

Comment: I am seeing that there is no any effect on the parallax !

Comment: click the center mouse button and drag the mouse a bit down and leave it then you will see the effect

Comment: please help me out i am stucked please !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you can see that as you scroll the first image comes over the heading "what are the things we do?".

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the extra space on the x-axis (on the right)?

**On the body, change `width: 100vw` to `width: 100%`.**

Or alternatively, add `max-width: 100%` (though I don't see any problem with `width: 100%` in this case since `body` will never get a smaller parent element).

---

It's a side effect of the v-scrollbar when trying to use 100vw. (`width[%]` takes the scrollbar into account but `width[vm]` doesn't).

Comment: I am not able to understand what are you trying to explain please explain in breif